# How to calculate a trend to use as a feature in a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

In a machine learning model one of the features is unemployment:

```
Month         Unemployment
May-2022      3.6%
Jun-2022      3.7%
Jul-2022      3.8%
Aug-2022      3.9%
```

What I need is to use as an additional feature the trend in the last three months, in this case it went up 0.1% each month, so the trend would be 0.3%? Note that I'm not looking to calculate the moving average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several choices:

- The trend can be calculated as $\frac{last - first}{first}$, e.g. $\frac{3.9 - 3.6}{3.6}$
- You can perform a linear regression including the 4 points and use the slope as trend.
- Or any variant, e.g. average difference: $\frac{(3.7-3.6)+(3.8-3.7)+(3.9-3.8)}{3}$.